# Request for Efficiency tips

Tags: vba, performance, excel-2010, processing-efficiency

I would like to make clear that the code I am posting works! The request I have is, I would like to make this code more efficient. I am still new to VBA although I am getting better :) The code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim MyLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellmatch

'Find the last row
MyLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


'Compare Records cell to Raw Data column and find a match
For i = 2 To MyLastRow

'Define our comparison
cellmatch = Application.Match(Cells(i, "C").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1), 0)
    If IsError(cellmatch) Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = "Not in Physical Inv"
    Else
        Cells(i, 4).Value = "-"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The code looks at a cell in column C. It then finds a duplicate in column A. If it finds it, it is a '-'. If not, it will say 'Not in Phys Inv'. My request is, how can I make this code more efficient? Also, if this is a question for a different forum, please let me know. I will close this out, as best as I can given my rank on this site, and move it to the appropriate place.

Comment: Your code has no obvious bottlenecks..............suggest you repost here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba

Comment: `Find` may work better than `Match`.  Other than that I'd say give your command button a real name - `CommandButton4` doesn't really say what the button does (maybe btnSearchInventory?)

Comment: Setting the cells' Value property is the most expensive thing you are doing here.  Google "vba disable automatic recalc" for a quick gain.

Comment: The other option is using a SQL statement instead with ADO. It may be a better approach if you have a lot of data. IMO, it makes the code easier to understand.